# r - Reordering only certain parts of a column in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a data frame of coordinates which lists points in the following order:

[image]

i.e. left to right in the first row, then right to left in the second row, etc.

I can generate all the points by doing this:

```
x_val <- -3:3; x_len <- length(x_val)
y_val <- -2:2; y_len <- length(y_val)
expand.grid(x=-x_lim:x_lim, y=y_lim:-y_lim)
```

[image]

But it's not in the right order so I tried this:

```
df <- lapply(1:y_len, function(i){
   data.frame(x=(-1)^(1+i)*x_val, 
              y=rep(-y_val[i],x_len))})

df <- do.call("rbind", df)
```

Although it works, is there a cleaner way to achieve what I want to do? Thanks.

Comment: Very interesting question: vote up!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is cleaner, but here it goes:

```
x_val <- -3:3; x_len <- length(x_val)
y_val <- -2:2; y_len <- length(y_val)
n <- x_len*y_len
x <- rep(c(x_val, rev(x_val)), n, length.out = n)
y <- sort(rep(c(y_val), n, length.out = n), decreasing =TRUE)
df <- data.frame(x, y)
```